# What is the name of the controller that turns a framebuffer to an LVDS signal?

Tags: lcd, lvds

I've been googling around for a bit and I'm having trouble coming up with the term for a device that takes in an address and a color and saves it to a frame buffer then sends that frame buffer over LVDS to some other device like an LCD.

Is this just an LCD controller?

Comment: You'ld probably have a CPU fill the memory and another device do the conversion to LVDS.  For that second part, the best solutions seems to be a DMA Engine and High Speed Data Converter.  But I'ld say there is not a single name for it.

Comment: "Display controller" seems as good a name as any - I'm not sure there is an "official" name for such a thing. When it's built into a micro, the manufacturer will give a name to that module - for example the LTDC (LCD-TFT display controller) in an STM32 or LCDC (Liquid Crystal Display Controller LCDC) in a Kinetis.